# What is the maximum length of a string that can be passed as a parameter to a jar file in java?

Tags: java, jar, byte

I am trying to execute the following line of code in order to use this specific jar file:

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec(jrePath+"/bin/java -jar C:/d/test.jar Method1 " + arg1+ " "+arg2+" ");
```

I am getting the following error:

> java.io.exception filename too long

This is because I am trying to pass a pdf as a byte. How do I fix this issue? It is important for my application to use the pdf in byte format. I tried compressing the byte string but even the compressed string is too long for execution.

Comment: Show the stack trace, it will show the java source and line number. My guess is that the bytes arg is taken as file name and the file open then gives that exception.

Comment: You can always take test.jar on your application's class path and call the test.jar's main class (see META-INF/MANIFEST.MF Main-Class) as: `TestMainClass.main(new String[] {"...", "...", "..."});`.

Comment: java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "C:\Program": CreateProcess error=206, The filename or extension is too long
No. Its only giving error when the string is too long. works for shorter strings.

Comment: You might try `Runtime.getRuntime().exec(new String[] {jrePath+"/bin/java", "-jar", "C:/d/test.jar", "Method1", arg1, arg2});` but it probably will be the same - though a better error message perhaps. Best use calling the test.jar's main from java immediately. Bytes as string will never work nevertheless.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the OS you use. For example, on Windows XP and later it should be 8191 symbols or so (see https://support.microsoft.com/ru-ru/kb/830473). Java is crossplatform so the length will change on different OS. Anyway, passing bytearrays from  command line in not recommended and would cause even more problems, such as encoding isues.

I'd suggest you modify your program so it writes the byte array to some file, passing its filename to second program and then the second program reads it from file.

Comment: The requirement is to sign a pdf without saving it locally. That's why i am trying to handle the bytes directly. If I saved the byte form to a file, it will be almost the same as saving the pdf, wouldn't it?